# How to create a FileUpload view / viewmodel that isn't an entity in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel

I am working on an auction application and I am creating a method so that the admins can submit an excel spreadsheet that will create a new auction and store it in the database. So first I made a class (model) `Uploadfile` like this:

```
[NotMapped]
public class UploadFile
{
    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase ExcelFile { get; set; }
}
```

I used `NotMapped` because I am trying to understand how to create and use models that aren't stored in my database and this is where my issue and misunderstanding lies.

I created a controller, which I did manually since `UploadFile` is not an entity with a key as such:

```
public class FileUploadsController : Controller
{
    private AuctionEntities db = new AuctionEntities();

    // GET: FileUploads
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UploadFile UploadFile = new UploadFile();
        return View(UploadFile);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UploadFile UploadFile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (UploadFile.ExcelFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                if (UploadFile.ExcelFile.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx") || UploadFile.ExcelFile.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
                {
                    XLWorkbook wb;

                    // in case if the file is corrupt
                    try
                    {
                        wb = new XLWorkbook(UploadFile.ExcelFile.InputStream);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, $"Check your file. {ex.Message}");
                        return View();
                    }

                    IXLWorksheet ws = null;

                    try   // in case the sheet you are looking for is not found
                    {
                        ws = wb.Worksheet("sheet1");
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "Sheet not found");
                        return View();
                    }

                    var firstRowUsed = ws.FirstRowUsed();
                    var auctionRow = firstRowUsed.RowUsed().RowBelow();

                    // create auction
                    string auctionName = auctionRow.Cell(1).Value.ToString();
                    DateTimeOffset startDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(auctionRow.Cell(2).Value.ToString());
                    DateTimeOffset endDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(auctionRow.Cell(3).Value.ToString());
                    string folderName = auctionRow.Cell(4).Value.ToString();

                    Models.Auction auction = new Models.Auction(auctionName, startDate, endDate, folderName);
                    db.Auctions.Add(auction);

                    // find the next table
                    var nextRow = auctionRow.RowBelow();

                    while (nextRow.IsEmpty())
                    {
                        nextRow = nextRow.RowBelow();
                    }

                    const int catNameCol = 1;
                    var catRow = nextRow.RowUsed().RowBelow();

                    // get categories from ws table and add to the auction
                    while (!catRow.Cell(catNameCol).IsEmpty())
                    {
                        string catName = catRow.Cell(1).Value.ToString();
                        int seqNo = Convert.ToInt32(catRow.Cell(2).Value.ToString());
                        string fileName = catRow.Cell(3).Value.ToString();

                        Cat cat = new Cat(auction.AuctionId, catName, seqNo, fileName);
                        auction.Cats.Add(cat);

                        catRow = catRow.RowBelow();
                    }

                    var findNextRow = catRow.RowBelow();

                    while (findNextRow.IsEmpty())
                    {
                        findNextRow = findNextRow.RowBelow();
                    }

                    const int itemNameCol = 1;

                    var itemRow = findNextRow.RowUsed().RowBelow();

                    while(!itemRow.Cell(itemNameCol).IsEmpty())
                    {
                        string itemName = itemRow.Cell(1).Value.ToString();
                        string itemDesc = itemRow.Cell(2).Value.ToString();
                        string catName = itemRow.Cell(3).Value.ToString();
                        string modelNo = itemRow.Cell(4).Value.ToString();
                        decimal retailValue = Convert.ToDecimal(itemRow.Cell(5).Value.ToString());
                        string fileName = itemRow.Cell(6).Value.ToString();
                        decimal initialBid = Convert.ToDecimal(itemRow.Cell(7).Value.ToString());
                        decimal increment = Convert.ToDecimal(itemRow.Cell(8).Value.ToString());
                        Cat itemCat = null;

                        foreach(var cat in auction.Cats)
                        {
                            if(catName == cat.CatName)
                            {
                                itemCat = cat;
                            }
                        }

                        Item item = new Item(itemName, itemDesc, modelNo, retailValue, fileName, startDate, endDate, initialBid, increment, null, null, null, itemCat);
                        itemCat.Items.Add(item);

                        itemRow = itemRow.RowBelow();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "Only .xlsx and .xls files are allowed");
                    return View();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "Not a valid file");
                return View();
            }
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

Next I thought I would try to create a view again so that I can display where the user uploads the file and see if my method works and this is where I have run into my lack of knowledge in asp.net.

So I tried to create a ViewModel as I have seen since the model I created before was a data model, so that I could use this viewmodel to display the upload on my view page. My ViewModel is simple and is:

```
public class FileUploadViewModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase ExcelFile { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I wanted to create a view page for this viewmodel and it is still treating this model has an entity and giving me an error that it does not have a key etc. I need a viewpage that can access a model with the Excel file in it and I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this. I have read up on viewmodels and I know how crucial they are in MVC, however I just can't seem to grasp on how to use them. Can someone please help me understand how to use one here?

Basically, I want to use this view page with my model or viewmodel:

Comment: You say the problem is with your view model, but it seems like the code you posted is irrelevant to that (aside from the view model class definition). What does your DbContext look like, and how are you creating your view model and attempting to display it? Is UploadFile suppose to be one of your entities? It doesn’t have a key.

Comment: UploadFile is not an entity. I am not wanting to store it or the uploaded files in my database at all. It merely was a way I thought to get the excel file into a controller so that I could do what I wanted to do.
What I am trying to accomplish is to have a view page that says "Click here to upload file" they upload there spreadsheet and the controller I posted does the rest of the work. I am trying to make a viewpage either with UploadedFile model or the viewmodel I created as the model I pass to the view so that I can accomplish this.

Comment: I added to my model folder both my model and the attempted viewmodel by right clicking and adding a class. That's the only way I know how to do it. It thinks that I want these classes as entities, thus I am getting errors when I try to create a view page using either one as the model

Comment: Ok, so unless I’m missing something, nothing just “becomes” an entity with explicitly registering it as a DbSet on your DbContext. Can you update the question with the exact error message?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746741/error-when-creating-controller-no-key-defined-and-not-mapped
Basically is this either with the same model or the "viewmodel" This post also explains I'm trying to following an example and use that view page for my application @cwharris

Comment: You do not need the `[NotMapped]` on your Upload class. That is your view model. Now create a view which is strongly typed to that view model and use it.

Comment: How do I create a view that is strongly typed in MVC 5? I see how to add a blank view or to create one off a model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My educated guess is that you are getting stuck in the "Add View" window.

You are probably selecting a template that requires a model (e.g. `Create`), selecting your `FileUploadViewModel` class as the model and also your context.

What this does is it causes the Visual Studio "wizard" to try to map the model internally to your context, which results on the error you see.

Instead, select `Empty (without model)` as the template which will gray out the `Model` and `Data Context` fields. Your view will then be created without errors.

You can then tell the view to expect your model by adding this at the top:

```
@model FileUploadViewModel
```

Make sure you fully qualify `FileUploadViewModel` (e.g. include the namespace in front).

Your methods should now use the model you specified at the top of the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    FileUploadViewModel UploadFile = new FileUploadViewModel();
    return View(UploadFile);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FileUploadViewModel UploadFile)
{

}
```

You do not need the `[NotMapped]` attribute anywhere here.

Comment: That was a great answer Juan. Exactly what I needed. And then when I call "Index" "FileUploads" it will know to use this page?

Comment: Like if I were to put an action link for this function on my "auction" "index" page?

Comment: @C.Math: An action link to the page will fire the signature without any parameters. Your view to upload the file will contain a form tag that will post back to the method marked with `[HttpPost]`.